# Passing a 2D array to a function creating another dimension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

Newbie confused again!

Nearly got to the end of my little project with the help of you fine folk but hit a snag and I can't work it out. Sure its a fundamental issue though.

The value below is just a single entry hence why it looks like a pointless use of a 2D array

I'm passing a 2D array called `micSumm` with the value

`[[1526857200000, 1527289200000, "HALL", "U89", 1]]`

To a function `chkDup` with `var arrA = chkDup(micSumm);` but for some reason as soon as the debugger jumps to the `function chkDup(elmnt){` piece of code the array dimension become `0[5][5]` in the debugger

Please help...again!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770392/arrays-keeps-growing-in-debugging-mode

Comment: Hi although this is a minimal example and probably verifiable, it isn't [mcve] . Post your complete code. The bug may not be where "you" think it is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was completely of my own making surprise, surprise. I'd put some code inside a `for` block by accident.

However the 'added dimension' issue seem to me to be a quirk of GAS like tehhowch implied. Here is a little test block in case anyone is able to verify for me:

```
function data(){
  var arrA = [[1,2,3,4,5]];
  var arrB = testFunction(arrA);
}

function testFunction(e){
  return e;
}
```

If you debug `data` and put a break at `var arrB = testFunction(arrA);` you can see that inner of `arrA` is `0[5]`. But if you then step in to `testFunction` and look at the contents of `e` its becomes `0[5][5]`

Would love to know of there's a valid reason for this. Doesn't seem to affect any further processing treating it as a 2D array.

Thanks